# Chain rule with partial derivatives II

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

In order to help my understanding I have an example I used previously,

> Let $\displaystyle u = f\left(\frac{y}{x}, \frac{z}{x}\right)$, then what is $\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \space$?

We have the format,

$u = f\left(g(x, y), h(x, z)\right)$

So can someone explain how to simply take a partial derivative like this?

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \nabla f \left(y/x, z/x \right) \cdot  \left( \frac{\partial (y/x)}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial (z/x)}{\partial x}\right)$$

This just chain rule. Write $c(x,y) = (f(x,y), h(x,z))$ and so $u(x,y) = (f \circ c)(x,y)$. Hence, taking the partial of $u$ with respect to $x$, means that we think of $y$ as a constant and so $c(x,y)$ is really just a function of $x$. In your text book you've covered $(f \circ c)'(t)$ i.e $c$ is a function of $1$-variable, but again that's exactly what this becomes since in the differentiation, $y$ is constant. I hope this helps.